# Is it possible to aggregate user statuses from Twitter and Facebook using javascript client-side scripting only?

Tags: javascript, json, facebook, twitter, cross-domain

I would like to make a web page that aggregates social sites like Twitter, Facebook, and others however I have no idea if this is possible considering cross domain security issues.  I've heard of JSONP but I've never used and don't know if that will work to get data from Twitter and Facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://remysharp.com/2007/05/18/add-twitter-to-your-blog-step-by-step/ That shows a JS based solution to get a timeline just through javascript. I presume you can do something similar for facebook (?)

Answer (score 1):

Neither Twitter nor Facebook provide JSONP.

You might be able do a javascript only aggregator site though using their javascript apis:

http://platform.twitter.com/js-api.html

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/